# Minimum space for Bitarray? (2.4.0)

Tags: ruby, integer

I'm implementing a Bitarray class in Ruby. By force of habbit I defined each element in the array as a 62-bit integer. Later I discovered that Ruby has merged Fixnum and Bignum into Integer. I can't really figure out how it works and my testing only made it more confusing.

Here is the implementation:

```
class Bitarray
    attr_accessor :field
    attr_accessor :size
    attr_accessor :bloc

    def initialize(size, default = false)
        @bloc = 62
        if default 
            @field = Array.new(size/@bloc+1, (1<<@bloc)-1)
        else
            @field = Array.new(size/@bloc+1, 0)
        end
        @size = size
    end

    def flip(position)
        @field[position/@bloc] ^= 1<<(position % @bloc)
        return
    end

    def [](position)
        raise "out of bounds" if @size <= position
        @field[position/@bloc][position % @bloc]
    end

    def []=(position, value)
        if value == 0
            flip(position) if self[position] == 1
        else
            flip(position) if self[position] == 0
        end
    end
end 

arr = Bitarray.new(1<<32, true)
```

I thought I could figure out the most compact implementation by changing the bloc size and observe system memory. Right out the gate I'm struck with an impossibility. 2^32 bits set to one should use 536,870,912 B or ~537 MB of memory but it only shows use of 394 MB. Are my bits going in to the fourth dimension or is ruby doing something sneaky?

When I changed the bloc size to 32bits all of a sudden I'm using 641 MB of system memory.
`(2**32-1).size #=> 4`
Clearly there must be something extra. Why is ruby lying? What bloc size should I be using to be most memory efficient while also avoiding big int bitwise operations? The goal is to be compact and fast.

My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

**EDIT:**
So I put my Bitarray into it's own file to completely isolate it.
I initialized it as 2^32 bits set to one like previously, it should be impossible to use less than ~537 MB.

**Bloc size => system memory use**

```
32  bits => ~521 MB
64  bits => ~266 MB
128 bits => ~137 MB 
# in a 64-bit system I shouldn't gain anything by increasing the size beyond that.
```

It is clear that Ruby is doing something fishy. What is it?

Comment: Why a 62-bit integer and not just an arbitrary sized binary string? Why 2.4.0 instead of the 2.7.0 that's available?

Comment: The first question you need to answer is "what is the size of an Integer in 64-bit Ruby?" Until you establish that you're scrabbling in the dark here.

Comment: @tadman Earlier versions of ruby had Fixnum as a 64-bit singned integer with 1 bit dedicated as Bignum flag. Thus using 63-bit bloc would add one more byte to each element using alot more memory + the added overhead of bitshifting bigint object resulting in (20% slowdown but don't quote me on that number). Using smaller than 62-bit bloc would still use 64-bits for each element wich would also result in memory waste but no performance gain or penalty. Did that answer your question? For the second question, the docs say that small integers are defined as 32-bit but that doesn't appear to be true

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your confusion about memory footprint doubling when you're using twice as many integers to represent the same data, then.

Comment: If the goal is to be "compact and fast", the most compact representation will always be a binary string. Using anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: Not sure I follow "binary string" if you are talking about just making single big integer then setting bits gets exponentially slower with size since ruby doesn't offer a way to flip individual bits. Thus you are stuck bitshifting 1 a milion times or worse.

Comment: If you don't understand my confusion look at it this way, my bit array had set 2^32 bits or ~537 MB. How could my entire application use less memory then that? And when I did the smaller bloc (in accordance with Ruby documentation) I ended up using a lot more memory than the advertised object should use.

Comment: Perhaps you're measuring the memory footprint incorrectly. The operating system may be doing things in the background as well to interfere with an accurate measurement. Did you run `GC.start` to force garbage collection before taking a reading?

Comment: For what it's worth, on my machine the 62-bit version uses ~554MB and the 32-bit one uses ~1061MB, which is really close to the 1073MB you'd expect with a pure linear scaling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209388/discussion-between-cookieninja-and-tadman).

Comment: CRuby's fixnums on Windows are always 32 bits wide (incl. sign and fixnum flag) since a fixnum is based on `long` and Windows is LLP64.

Comment: @cremno - yea just finished a benchmark test. It showed a substantial performance hit after bloc size of 30-bits wich would coroborate what you said.